# how to search for keyword: value in kwargs

Tags: python, decorator

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv0ZH.png)

"""CODE"""

```
from functools import wraps

def ensure_authorized(fn):

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if {'role','admin'} == kwargs:
            return "Shh! Don't tell anybody!"

        return wrapper

@ensure_authorized
def show_secrets(*args, **kwargs):
    return "Shh! Don't tell anybody!"

print(show_secrets(role="admin"))
```

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself as text: no images or links to outside resources.

Comment: thanks for the info, will do next time

Answer (score 0):

`if kwargs.get("role") == "admin": …`